# Which Azure API versions does Terraform support?

Tags: azure, terraform

How up to date is the Azure API versions support in Terraform?

Just as an example, the current [Storage Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts?source=recommendations) API version is 2022-09-01. I couldn't see in the Terraform docs what's their latest supported API version. In their docs a [default_service_version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account#default_service_version) is mentioned which defaults to 2020-06-12 (2020!), but well, that's just the default.

So in general, how up to date is the Azure API versions support in Terraform? Where to find a list of the latest supported API versions? How fast is Terraform implementing new Azure API versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the latest updates on the versions in azure can be checked here in [Terraform AzureRM provider version history | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/provider-version-history-azurerm)

[image]

The required provider versions can be changed according to the compatible version .

[image]

And for storage account for example:
You can check the versions here [Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts 2021-06-01 - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2021-06-01/storageaccounts?pivots=deployment-language-terraform)

[image]

In storage , you can see the latest version as [2022-05-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2022-05-01/storageaccounts/blobservices?source=recommendations&pivots=deployment-language-terraform)

Comment: awesome, thanks for these detailed informations! I am surprised to find so much about Terraform on the Microsoft website. Do you know if there is any kind of special cooperation between them?